# CSS table inside a table?

Tags: html, css

i was trying to put table inside a table like this:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Filename</td>
                    <td>Size</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>my cool file name</td>
                            <td>654 KB</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

the reason i want to do this is to set the second table a height
and than overflow:auto so the second table have a scroll bar to scroll down
is that possible , and it it does , how?

Comment: The others have the correct answer.  For completeness sake here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/33xYe/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need a `<td>`/`<th>` within a `<tr>` tag, so add either of those between your `<tr>` & nested `<table>` (and probably apply `colspan="2"`)

Also, off the top of my head I'm not sure if the `<td>`/`<th>` supports an overflow with scrolling, but if not you can always wrap the nested `<table>` in a `<div>` and style it.

Comment: you have to wrap the '<table>' element into a div to apply styling, like the following '<div style="height: 60px;  overflow: auto;">'

Comment: @danyloid: Agreed. And for the OP, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/9F9db/). (and another one with scrolling in both directions: http://jsfiddle.net/9F9db/2/)

Answer (score 2):

`<table>` isn't valid inside `<tr>`.  Put it inside a `<td>` inside a `<tr>` instead.

Like this:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Filename</td>
                <td>Size</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <!--  ** add this ** -->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>my cool file name</td>
                        <td>654 KB</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td> <!--  ** add this ** -->
            </tr>
        </table>
```